# OfficeJS Excel: how to access and modify Floor, Side Wall and Back Wall of a 3D chart in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I do not see any references to Wall objects inside Excel.Chart object???

Without Walls and Floors certain charts are not possible because hiding majorGridlines removes the very top and bottom line which I need to keep....modifying floor and back wall line styles gives me the look that I need but since they are not accessible via OfficeJS the project is getting burned.

Is Wall/Floor not yet supported in OfficeJS? Seems like a fundamental object...Any timelines when it will be available? I cannot even find it in preview API...and it is end of 2022...

Answer (score 0):

3D chart is not fully support on Excel Online, and I don't think there is such API for now. I'd recommend going to Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum to request a new feature.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Comment: It is almost 2023 so you would assume 6 years would be enough for MS to provide these features...turns out it is not...which is too bad....